# Discord api banner change

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to change my discord bot's banner to an animated one for which I want to update it using the api.

I tried looking up in the api reference but it was only showing username and avatar parameters in patch @api/v9/users@me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code and endpoint to change your bot's banner to a `.gif` file.

```js
await client.rest.patch("/users/@me", { body: { banner: "data:image/gif;base64," + Buffer.from(await (await fetch(image.url)).arrayBuffer()).toString('base64') } });
```

*Make sure to change the image variable to something that would be accepted by the API*

Answer (score 0):

this does it:

```js
const {
    REST,
    Routes,
    DataResolver
} = require("discord.js");

const rest = new REST().setToken(client.token);

        await rest.patch(Routes.user(), {

            body: {
                banner: await DataResolver.resolveImage("https://i.giphy.com/WwCdUxURlrwSQM4FfS.gif")
            },

        });
```